# Set the DropDown using index number

Tags: vba, excel

There is a macro to read a file which contains a number. According to that number, a "Drop Down" in the spread sheet should be assigned. It means if for example the number was 2, the Drop Down should be set on second item of the Drop Down list.

What would be the code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim myFile As String

myFile = "C:\sales.csv"

Open myFile For Input As #1

    Line Input #1, DataLine 
    MsgBox DataLine

Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your combo's name is ComboBox1 on a UserForm, replace `MsgBox DataLine` with this:

```
ComboBox1.ListIndex = DataLine - 1 '<~~ -1 because zero-based
```

For a Drop-Down control located on a Worksheet, named for example "Drop down 14":

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 14").OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex = DataLine
' 1-based in this case
```

you can get the name of the control by right-clicking it and looking in the "Name Box" on the top-left, near the formula bar.

Comment: It is clear except how would I figure out the name of the Combobox? When I click on the combobox, on the top left of the sheet, the name is "Drop Down 14". So I did:

`Set dd = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 14").OLEFormat.Object
            dd.ListIndex = DataLine - 1`

It works, but is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Ah ok, thought the object was on a userform (will edit to answer the two cases). Your method to get the object is fine. Do you still have issues with it?